# How to resolve SSL connection alert in Blackberry webworks + phonegap in Blackberry OS 6,7?

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry

I have developed an application for Blackberry(OS 6 &7 ) using Blackberry webworks sdk & Phonegap (HTML5). every thing is working fine except SSL connection alert. I am calling secure connection (https) using ajax calling. At the time of secure connection hit mobile showing an alert and says "Do you want to allow this secure connection" and gives 3 buttons 1. Continue 2. Stop  3. Cancel. Client don't want this alert while connecting to secure connection. How can i remove this alert. I searched google more than a week but could not find any solution.
Please get me out of this. more over I am working for Blackberry OS 6 & 7.

Regards,
Srinu.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Web Security alltogether.

It's not pretty but it should get rid of the prompt.
Just add

```
<preference name="websecurity" value="disable" />
```

to your config.xml

Comment: Hi @Max, I tried the solution you suggested, but no use, still I am getting the same alert dialog.